# Revealing a letter in a word game

Tags: java, arrays, string, char, shuffle

I am making a word game as homework. But I'm stuck. I have a shuffled word but I need to reveal its first (then 2nd,3rd...) letter per turn. I tried to do something like this :

```
char[] arr = a.toCharArray();
   for ( int j = 0; j<arr.length; j++) {

          if (original[j] == shuffled[j] ) { //If the not shuffled word's first letter equals to shuffled word's first letter then move to the 2nd letter and reveal it. Maybe update the j to j+1?}

          else {
            char temp = shuffled[j];
            shuffled[j] = original[j];
            original[j] = temp;
            String h = new String(shuffled);
            System.out.println("test " + h) ; 

          }
        }
```

**My output should be something like this :**

Original word : Badger
Shuffled word : drBage

1st turn : Brdage

2nd turn : Badrge

3rd turn : Badegr

4th turn : Badger

**My Current output is :**

Original word : Cat123

shuff 12Cta3

test C2Cta3

test CaCta3

test Catta3

test Cat1a3

test Cat123

test Cat123

Comment: What are you currently getting? Here on Stackoverflow, it is appropriate to state what's currently not working. And it would help to know what your current output is.

Comment: added my current output. @peeskillet

Comment: How does it not work? What are you _expecting_ to see as the output?

Comment: Current output does reveals the letters one by one. Look at my current output it does C2Cta3. Yes it reveal first letter but the 3rd letter is also the C. What I want to do is make it C21ta3. Replaced C and 1. @peeskillet

Comment: What is the pattern/order in which you want it shuffled?

Comment: It reveals the first letter first then 2nd then 3rd... But if the first letter of the shuffled word is equal to first letter of the original word it moves to the 2nd letter and reveals it instead. @peeskillet

Comment: I guess I don't get what you mean by "reveal"

Comment: It just shows the original letter, kind of a hint to give the player an idea what the word might be. 12Cta3 ---> C21ta3. It is a simple word game it shuffles the words and for per turn it shows the original letter with the order I explained. @peeskillet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following pseudo code should help clarify your problem. I would invoke a function, for example reveal letter which I have defined below after each turn.

```
   public class Unscramble{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        char[] orig = args[0].toCharArray();
        char[] shuffled = args[1].toCharArray(); 
        int count = 0;

        while(count < orig.length){

            if(!(orig[count] == shuffled[count]))
                shuffled = revealLetter(shuffled,orig, count);

            count++;
            System.out.println(count + " " + new String(shuffled));
        }
    }


    /*
    * Reveal letter
    * @param shuffled the shuffled array
    * @param original original char array
    * @param index index of letter to reveal
    */
    public static char[] revealLetter(char[] shuffled, char[] original, int index){
      shuffled[index] = original[index];
      return shuffled;
    }
}
```

Comment: revealNo is int index? @Hmm

Comment: With this (I changed int index to int revealNo) my output is : shuffled word : 1g2Do3
, new word : Dgg123 (infinite loop) @hmm

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't shuffle the word - you'll lose the right letter order.

Instead:

- loop through the letters
- print the first "n" letters from the original word
- make a copy of the array from n+ to end
- shuffle it then print it

Comment: I have the right letter order in a different char[] variable (original[] ) which later I converted to char[]. I've tried like 3 different ways to do this but none of them worked. @Bohemian